# Exclude Null Values

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I currently have a database where i collect the following. Currently trying to exclude all the null values and just keep the data entries.

```
with hipot_results as (
select *
from pico_bi.build_action_detailed_results b
join pico_bi.active_action_ref r on b.action_id = r.action_id
join pico_bi.build_data e on b.build_id = e.build_id
where r.action_label = 'Hipot Test'
order by created_at desc
limit 100)

select 
serial_number,
case when (step -> 'id')::numeric = '1' then (step -> 'measurement' ->> 'value')::numeric END as "IR-1 MΩ",
case when (step -> 'id')::numeric = '2' then (step -> 'measurement' ->> 'value')::numeric END as "LeakCurrent µA",
case when (step -> 'id')::numeric = '3' then (step -> 'measurement' ->> 'value')::numeric END as "IR-2 MΩ"
from hipot_results , jsonb_array_elements(action_detail -> 'steps') step
where serial_number = 'S226819'
```

current query.

[Current Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8snFM.png)

[Expected Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t348Y.png)

Comment: juse use min() or max() of each column assuming you can take 1 value from each and group by serial number.  Wrap case statements in max() and group by serial_number

Answer (score 0):

if we can assume for each serial number, each column will only be populated once, or you're willing to take the "Max" value when duplicates exist...

```
with hipot_results as (
select *
from pico_bi.build_action_detailed_results b
join pico_bi.active_action_ref r on b.action_id = r.action_id
join pico_bi.build_data e on b.build_id = e.build_id
where r.action_label = 'Hipot Test'
order by created_at desc
limit 100)

SELECT 
serial_number,
max(case when (step -> 'id')::numeric = '1' then (step -> 'measurement' ->> 'value')::numeric END) as "IR-1 MΩ",
max(case when (step -> 'id')::numeric = '2' then (step -> 'measurement' ->> 'value')::numeric END) as "LeakCurrent µA",
max(case when (step -> 'id')::numeric = '3' then (step -> 'measurement' ->> 'value')::numeric END) as "IR-2 MΩ"
FROM hipot_results , jsonb_array_elements(action_detail -> 'steps') step
GROUP BY Serial_number
```